# Buffer has wrong number of dimension error when trying to plot a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, buffer, line-plot

I am trying to draw (line plots) the columns of a dataFrame whose head looks like

```
df.head()

        (-0.1, -0.0075] (-0.0075, 0.0]  (0.0, 0.0075]   (0.0075, 0.1]
date                
20160104    0.013856    0.001777    0.000376    0.008512
20160105    0.026766    0.008370    0.004894    0.022094
20160106    0.041032    0.011879    0.008732    0.031421
20160107    0.060725    0.013530    0.008399    0.032522
20160108    0.078791    0.014628    0.011928    0.045840
```

The command I tried is

```
df.plot()
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

Help appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `df.date.plot.line()`?

Comment: Just did. I get the same error :(

Comment: It's possible that you have an extra column or something that's making a duplicate column name. Can you successively delete columns and see which delete makes the problem go away? I had the problem with a multiIndex and changed the mask series so that it got rid of an extra column and voila! The problem went away.